# Does Xcode 4.0.2 supports deployment target 3.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, deployment-target

I am going to upgrade Xcode 3.2.5 to Xcode 4.0.2 so do this new version supports deployment target 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can still set the deployment target to iOS 3.0 with Xcode 4.0.2 but you have to use the iOS 4.3 SDK as the base SDK.  It is the only supported option for the base SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If going from the accepted answer here:
[How can I build in XCode 4, for an iOS 3.1 deployment target, using libSystem.B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346250/how-can-i-build-in-xcode-4-for-an-ios-3-1-deployment-target-using-libsystem-b)

as well as the wikipedia page:

> Xcode 4.0 drops support for many older
>   systems, including all PowerPC
>   development as well as SDKs for 10.4
>   and 10.5, and all iOS SDKs older than
>   4.3. The deployment target can still be set to produce binaries for those
>   older platforms, however for Mac OS X
>   applications only x86 and x86_64
>   binaries can be produced.

yes, you can target iOS 3.0 using XCode 4 (but I have no idea how you do that)

Edit: I found this on a forum, it should let you target iOS 3.0

> - In your X-Code project, select Edit project settings inside the "Project"
>     sub-menu.
> - Once there, click the Build tab.
> - Make sure you select All configurations in the "Configuration"
>     option.
> - In the Base SDK option select iPhone Device 4.0
> - Search for the iPhone OS Desployment Target and select iPhone OS 3.0

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/53167-compile-ios-3-0-using-xcode-4-a.html#post221406