# Any idea what's "dyld: Symbol not found: ___gcc_personality_sj0" when compiling iOS app?

Tags: ios, gcc, dyld

My app crashes while loading dynamic library, which I don't explicitly request.

Full crash:

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
dyld: Symbol not found: ___gcc_personality_sj0
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/44B11CD4-6109-4970-88E9-467552DB86DD/Pro.app/Pro
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /var/mobile/Applications/44B11CD4-6109-4970-88E9-467552DB86DD/Pro.app/Pro
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [weak linking to libSystem.B.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346250/how-can-i-build-in-xcode-4-for-an-ios-3-1-deployment-target-using-libsystem-b/5426277#5426277).

> In your project build settings under "Other Linker Flags" add the
>   following:
>
> -weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>
> It should automatically be added to your Target build settings but if
>   it isn't you should add it there as well.