# How fix this error Library not found for -lSystem.B

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios-simulator

When i run app on IPhone simulator 5.1 i receive error

**Library not found for -lSystem.B**

But when in run on my iPhone (iOS 5.1), app run without errors.

How fix this error?

Comment: See [Alternate Stack Overflow Thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346250/how-can-i-build-in-xcode-4-for-an-ios-3-1-deployment-target-using-libsystem-b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this error: copy **libSystem.B.dylib** file from

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib`

to

`Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/usr/lib`